# In the figure, AT = a and BC= b , calculate R

Tags: geometry

In the figure, AT = a and BC= b , calculate R[image]
This is a difficult Peruvian book problem. Can not resolve. I would be grateful if someone manages to solve

I identif is that the quadrilateral DCBT is cyclic:
$ \angle BCD + \angle BTD = 180^o \rightarrow 
\angle ABT = \angle CDT\\\text{assuming T is tangency point:} \angle ATB = \angle TDA\\
\text{I don't have more ideas}\\
S:\frac{a(4c^2-b^2)}{4bc}$

Comment: Typo: it should be $\angle ABT = \angle CDT$

Comment: I don't understand why should we have $\angle ATD = \angle TDA$ . Are you sure these are written correctly?

Comment: What do we know about the circle with radius $c$ ? Do we know anything about its intersection with $AD$ ?

Comment: Saeed, You´re  correct. < ABT = < CDT. e ATB = TDA I've already done the correction

Comment: What is S? Why you have this equation?

Comment: @Moti Probably solution. Is angle at A 90?

Comment: Nothing is said about A

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image]
sirous, I discovered with some colleagues the solution. The correct image needs to be like this
$ M=l, KH = n, R =x\\
Power~of~ a~ point: ATD \rightarrow  \boxed{a^2=l(l+x)}(I)\\
 \measuredangle CHD=90^o\rightarrow H \in \bigcirc CD  \\
TdA = \theta\\TK ~ is~  bissector \rightarrow \measuredangle AtH \cong \measuredangle TdA \\
BCDT  ~is ~  inscriptible \rightarrow \measuredangle CbD\cong \measuredangle CtD = 90^o -\theta\\ \triangle BCD \sim \triangle KTH \\
\boxed{\frac{b}{2c}=\frac{n}{TH}}(II) \rightarrow (II)^2: \boxed{\frac{b^2}{4c^2}=\frac{n^2}{TH^2}} (III)\\
\triangle KTD:\boxed{TH^2=n\cdot 2x} (IV)\\ (IV) in(III):  n=\frac{(2xb^2)}{(4c^2)}\\
Triangle ~Angle~ Bisector~ Theorem  \triangle ATH: \frac{a}{l} = \frac{TH}{n} \rightarrow \boxed{l=\frac{a \cdot n}{TH}} (V) \\
(IV) in(V)^2:  
l^2=\frac{(na^2)}{(2x)}\\
(II) in(V): l=\frac{(ab)}{(2c)}\rightarrow in(I):
a^2=\frac{ab}{2c}(\frac{ab}{2c}+2x)\rightarrow x =\frac{2ca^2}{2ab}-\frac{ab}{4c}\rightarrow\\ x = \frac{4c^2a^2-a^2b^2}{4abc}\\
\therefore\boxed{\color{red}{x=\frac{a(4c²−b²)}{4bc}}}$

Answer (score 1):

[image]

Comment: Statement of question can  be as follows:

In figure $AT=a$, such that $AB=AF$. $BC=b$ and $CE=c$, find radius R on diameter FD.

Solution: Triangle ABF is isosceles , we have:

$\angle ABF=\frac{180-45}2=67.5$

$AB=\frac{AT}{\tan 67.5}$

In triangle ACD we have:

$AD=\sqrt 2(AB+BC)$

$\Rightarrow AD=\sqrt 2\big(\frac a{\tan 67.5} +b\big)$

$\Rightarrow  2R=FD=AD-(AF=AB)=\big(\frac a{\tan 67.5}+b\big)$

$\Rightarrow R=\frac 12\cdot \frac a {\tan 67.5} \big(\sqrt 2 -1\big)+ b\sqrt 2 \space \space\space\space\space (1)$

For example : a=50, b=75 we get $R=58.4$ which satisfies following relation:

$R\approx \frac {a(4c^2-b^2)}{bc}\space\space\space\space\space\space(2)$

Comment: sirous, thanks but why ABF isosceles? You considered BA perpendicular to AT. The figure does not show this. Is it possible to solve without this condition?

Comment: Plotting in geogebra AB is different from AF

Comment: And using your data in the solution we will have R = 14.58

Comment: @petaarantes, In statement we assume At=a such that ABF is isosceles.This mean value of a copaired with measure of the side of square is such that AB=AF.

Comment: @petaarantes, if you mean value of R from formula 1 it is $R\approx 55$.

Comment: @petaarantes Also you do not have to use the measure in the figure. Draw the square take AB=AF, extend BF to touch the top side of square. measure it for value of a. Now you can also have measure of b. Calculate R by putting  these measure in (1) and compare it with measure in your figure.

Comment: that is not necessarily a square

Comment: "if you mean value of R from formula 1 it is R \approx 55"  \\ I mean , using your data in the solution we will have R≈14,58\\ a(4c^2-b^2)/4bc

Comment: @petaarantes, there is no '4' in numerator of formula (2). that is your formula can not be correct.

Comment: but the problem is to demonstrate the algebraic result [a(4c^2-b^2)]/bc